# MATLAB - Create repeated sequences of ones and zeros with loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to create a single column vector (`out`), which is comprised of a sequence of ones and zeros. These should occur in sets of length `B` and `C` respectively, which are repeated `A` number of times. For example:

```
out=[1
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0]
```

It is currently set up as:

```
out=[0];  %not ideal, but used to initially define 'out'
A=3;
B=1;
C=2;

for i = 1:length(A)

    for ii = 1:length(B)
        out(end+1,1) = ones(ii,1);
    end

    for iii = 1:length(C)
        out(end+1,1) = zeros(iii,1);
    end

end
```

This is not working - current output:

```
out=[0
     1
     0]
```

How can I correct these loops to get the desired output? Also, is there a better way of achieving this with the given the inputs?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think you should just replace length(A), length(B), length(C) to A, B,C

Comment: `repmat([ones(B,1);zeros(C,1)],A,1)`

Comment: Thank you David. This provides the correct output in the simplest manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You do not need to use `length` as this returns the length of an array type, so A,B,C will all be length of 1.

2) Just directly use the values as shown below. Also you can initialize an empty array with empty brackets `[]`

3) If you're using the `zeros` and `ones` commands, these generate whole arrays/matrices and do not need to be in a loop. If you want to keep your loop version, just use `=1` or `=0`

```
out=[];  %--> you can use this instead
A=3;
B=1;
C=2;

for i = 1:A
    out(end+1:end+B,1) = ones(B,1);
    out(end+1:end+C,1) = zeros(C,1);    
end
```

... or of course to be more "Matlaby" just do what David said in the comments `repmat([ones(B,1);zeros(C,1)],A,1)`, but the above is there to help you on your way.

Comment: That does not solve the problem: `Subscripted assignment dimension
mismatch.`

Comment: Ooops. There was more wrong with it than met the eye. Try that

Comment: The problem remains. Correct is `out(end+1:end+B,1) = ones(B,1)` or even simpler `out(end+1:end+B,1) = 1`

Comment: Derp. It's late. Try that

Comment: Thanks for outlining the problems with my code and the different solution options. I can confirm that the loop option, as well as the repmat option, works.

Answer (score 1):

How about some modulo arithmetic?

```
result = double(mod(0:(B+C)*A-1, B+C)<B).';
```

Example:

```
>> B = 2; %// number of ones in each period
>> C = 4; %// number of zeros in each period
>> A = 3; %// number of periods
>> result = double(mod(0:(B+C)*A-1, B+C)<B).'
result =
     1
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 2 ways:
a)Using for loop-

```
A=3;
B=2;
C=3;
OneVector=ones(1,B);   % B is the length of ones.
zeroVector=zeros(1,C); % C is the length of zeros.

combinedVector=cat(2,OneVector,zeroVector);

Warehouse=[];  % to save data
for(i=1:A)
Warehouse=cat(2,Warehouse,combinedVector);
end
```

b)using repmat:

```
OneVector=ones(1,B);   % B is the length of ones.
zeroVector=zeros(1,C); % C is the length of zeros.
combinedVector=cat(2,OneVector,zeroVector);
Warehouse=repmat(combinedVector, [A,1]);
```

I hope, this will solve your problem.